# Install ImageMagick on Ubuntu with most filetype support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, imagemagick

I installed ImageMagick on Ubuntu server 10 by `apt-get install imagmagick`

but when I execute `identify filename`, I got an error

> identify: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/upload/0a2ff9ddd4f0510f7b1ff5a30f975c10' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/533.

I execute `identify -list format`, I don't see JPEG, PNG these common format in the list.

the full list of this command

http://notes.li/upload/im-format.txt

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you show the full error?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im it is the full error

Answer (score 0):

Do you have libpng (e.g. libpng12-0) and libjpeg (libjpeg62) properly installed? 
Which Ubuntu version are you using? Which imagemagick version are you using? Are you sure your file /tmp/upload/0a2ff9ddd4f0510f7b1ff5a30f975c10 is a file, which identify should recognize?

In your apt-get command one "e" is missing in the package name.